# how to use html5 link preload js resource

Tags: html

1. Here is my link code and I can not see this Javascript resource load when page refreshed:-

   ```
   <link rel="preload" href="/dist/build.gbk.js" as="script">
   ```
2. How can I ensure that link worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update :

`<link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script">`

This means that the browser will preload the JavaScript file, but not actually use it yet.

To use it, you could do this when desired:

```
var preloadedScript = document.createElement("script");
preloadedScript.src = "main.js";
document.body.appendChild(preloadedScript);
```

This is useful when you want to preload a script, but then defer executing it until exactly when you need it.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: No.What I need is `preload` resource.Not run that script in this page.

Comment: Initially i got the question wrong. Check the update.

Comment: Thanks.But I found that `link` worked in `Chrome` not in `FireFox` (57,my version).Should I use `ajax` to fetch the js resource in other browser?

Comment: If you can explain why exactly you want to preload, I can give suggestions.

Comment: I just want to preload `bundle.gbk.js `. That is a big js file.So I want to preload that to save loading time on next edit page.

Comment: For next page you can use `<link rel="prefetch">`